# In jquery Validate Plugin - sale tax amount validation based on drop down value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Can anyone help on this please? That error message is not displaying based on the condition.
If drop down value is 0 or 2 then sale tax amount should be 0 or else error should throw.
If drop down value is 1 then sale tax amount should be greater than 0 or else error should throw. These things should be happen. But here some issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/SbR6b/1/

Comment: What exact problem you are facing with the provided code ?

Comment: @Sivasenthil : what is 'taxtype' in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now check http://jsfiddle.net/SbR6b/15/.. it is modified according to the question.

Comment: how can i make separate error message according that value. I mean,e.g, Enter tax amount greater than 0 or Enter tax amount should be 0.